# User to User Payment in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, e-commerce

I'm looking to implement a payment system in my rails application which allows user to charge each other for services and I will be collecting a small fee from this transfer. I have looked around for a long time but most services such as Stripe do not support customer to customer transfers. I am a bit lost as to how to implement this therefore I would appreciate any help I can get.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You won't find this kind of anwsers here, StackOverflow can help developers to find answers to a specific coding question, not to a general design request like your

Comment: I definitely think it applies since there must be a way to implement this. Nothing that I know of can do what I require either through coding or otherwise.

Comment: Check FAQ and you'll get better understanding of stack overflow purpose http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Stripe can do user to user transactions with an application fee:

https://stripe.com/connect

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have seen connect before but I would prefer to use it as a last resort if I can't find something which simply allows users to input their credit card and have it transferred to it.

Comment: thats not how credit cards work..